# check when the array has finished shuffling to do some operation

Tags: arrays, swift

I am using `array.shuffle()` to reorder the content of an array randomly, I want to check when the array has finished shuffling to do some operations because I found that when I just put the code after `array.shuffle()` the array didn't finish shuffling and the code was fired. thank you for your help!

Comment: The `shuffle()` method is synchronous, it has finished when it returns. – Your actual problem must be something different. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wait or something as the method `shuffle` is synchronous , which means next line will run after it finishes shuffling

```
var arr = ["1","2","3"]
arr.shuffle()
print(arr) // ["2", "1", "3"]
```